# GWT Designer - Right tool for GWT Enterprise Application

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I need your opinion based on your experience working with Large Scale GWT Based Application.

The question is :

is GWT Designer Right tool for Big GWT Application where they are cool CSS and Dynamics Widgets are created? Can the designer (Not having much Knowledge of Java) use that tool to create layouts of GWT Application?

OR we should go with an approach where they provide HTML + CSS and using UiBinder HTMLPanel approach we utilize their Design and our Java Skills to achieve the required results.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards, Niraj.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same situation at my job.  My personal feeling is that we should not expect designers to be using a tool like Eclipse/GWT Designer.  If they are true graphic designers, then they will likely not be thrilled about being forced into using this tool.

Beyond that, I'm a strong believer that hand written code (as opposed to generated code out of Designer) is much cleaner and easier to maintain in the long run.

Also take into consideration whether or not you're in a highly stylized application.  I would argue that doing any heavy lifting in CSS might be more of a challenge in a GWT Designer environment.  Using UiBinder, you have direct access to the DOM and the CSS.

My $.02